# How to change python string into pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

fellow developers in the StackOverflow.
I have string data in
`'key=apple; age=10; key=boy; age=3'`
How can we convert it into the pandas' data frame such that key and age will be the header and all the values in the column?

```
key   age
apple 10
boy   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = 'key=apple; age=10; key=boy; age=3'
words = data.split(";")
key = []
age = []

for word in words:
    if "key" in word:
        key.append(word.split("=")[1])
    else:
        age.append(word.split("=")[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(key, columns=["key"])
df["age"] = age

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
str_stream = 'key=apple; age=10; key=boy; age=3'
lst_kv = str_stream.split(';')   
# lst_kv => ['key=apple', ' age=10', ' key=boy', ' age=3']

res= [{s.split('=')[0].strip(): s.split('=')[1] for s in lst_kv[i:i+2]} 
      for i in range(len(lst_kv)//2)
     ]
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df
```

Output:

```
    key     age
0   apple   10
1   boy     10
```

More explanation for one line `res` :

```
res = []
for i in range(len(lst_kv)//2):
    dct_tmp = {}
    for s in lst_kv[i:i+2]:
        kv = s.split('=')
        dct_tmp[kv[0].strip()] = kv[1]
    res.append(dct_tmp)
res
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'apple', 'age': '10'}, {'age': '10', 'key': 'boy'}]
```